# Bind mediacontroller to the certain view

Tags: android, scroll, mediacontroller

I have next views in activity:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This activity has a lot of text so in can scroll. I tried to set `view` as a anchor for the mediacontroller but mediacontroller is always positioned at the screen bottom (even while scrolling).

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
controller.setAnchorView(view);
```

My question is how to bind mediacontroller to a `view` so it can scroll with `view`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using view you can use videoview. You can add media controller to videoview. Also it will scroll with scrollview.

Use below code it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/xyzString"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:focusable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It is still at the bottom

Comment: can you explain diagramatically what exactly you want? As you have taken linear layout, it will be placed after text only.

Comment: Yes I want mediacontroller to position in the fixed place (inside view). So when view is not seen on screen (because of large text for instance) mediacontroller also is not seen. When scroll down mediacontroller appears with view.

Comment: thanks, it is very helpful answer, but I decided to create custom mediacontroller instead